# Запрет ввода двух точек в одном числе

Tags: python, алгоритм, tkinter

Написал калькулятор на Tkinter + python3. Получил такой баг с плавающей точкой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, один раз точка ставится и больше нет.

```
def append_item_dot(self, x):
        get_result = self.exp_field.cget("text")
        if get_result.count(".") == 0 and len(get_result) > 0:
            get_result = get_result + x
            self.exp_field["text"] = str(get_result)
```

Пробовал переписывать по другому, там получается так 3.3.4 + 6..
То есть я хочу, что бы можно было поставить одну точку до какой-то операции потом ещё одну.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 def append_item_dot(self, x):
        get_result = self.exp_field.cget("text")
        if len(get_result) > 0 and get_result[-1].isdigit():
            get_result = str(get_result) + x
            self.exp_field["text"] = str(get_result)
```

---

`self.exp_field.cget("text")` при нажатии на кнопку тянет содержимое с виджета:

```
label self.exp_field = Label(self.app, text="0",anchor='ne', font=self.myFont,)
self.exp_field.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, ipadx=30, sticky="news", )
```

А `x` - это число которое передается при нажатии любой кнопки.

Comment: Либо выложи работоспособный пример, тогда я посмотрю, либо подожди тех, кто помнит TK.

Comment: Спасибо, буду переписывать, через словарь... =) извените за беспокойство

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно проверять, что точка есть только во вводимом в данный момент числе, а не во всей строке.

Алгоритм такой:

Идем по строке с конца, пока все символы - цифры. Как только встретилась не цифра, возвращаем этот символ. Если дошли до начала строки, тоже возвращаем какой-то специальный объект (например, текст `'start'`, в принципе даже все равно что, главное чтобы отличалось от точки).

Дальше смотрим что у нас вернулось: если точка, то еще одну точку поставить нельзя. Если что-то другое, то можно.

Реализация:

```
def find_dot(s):
    for c in reversed(s):
        if not c.isdigit():
            return c
    return 'start'

print(find_dot('123'))  # start - ставить точку можно
print(find_dot('123.45'))  # . - ставить точку нельзя
print(find_dot('12.34+123'))  # + - ставить точку можно
print(find_dot('1.23e23')) # e - можно
```

Если курсор может быть в середине строки, то от позиции курсора нужно идти влево и вправо (два отдельных цикла) до первой не цифры и точно так же проверять, является ли найденный символ точкой или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже потом понял что ваш код действительно помог в моей проблеме